# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f\left(1/x\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus* I came upon the following problem (Chapter 5, Nr. 31):

**Proposition:** $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$

I came up with a different answer than the author, so I propose it here.

**Proof:**

We have $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} x$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} x = \infty$, which completes the proof. $\square$

I already checked my proofs for $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} x = \infty$ and since they are quick and found elsewhere on the internet, I omit them here.

I am unsure of the assumption $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) \iff \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} x$$

Can this be deduced from the definition of functions in general? If not and it can be proofed with somewhat elementary measures, I would be grateful for help or hints. Thank's in advance.

Comment: Are you meant to prove the claim, as in *argue from the definition of limit?* Or are you satisfied with the manipulation of symbols, including writing equations of the form $\infty = \infty$ as stand-ins for more rigorous arguments?

Comment: There is meaning for the complete sentence "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$". There is not such meaning to the standalone symbol "∞". So applying transitivity of the equals sign and writing "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty=\lim\limits_{x\to b}g(x)$" is questionable. This exercise doubtless wants you to really think about what the definitions of limits are instead. The goal is not to prove the cited proposition; the goal is for the student/reader to internalize those definitions more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive argument is basically what you wrote on your question. However, that is not a rigorous argument as Sammy mentioned in the comment. A rigorous argument could be built from the following statements:

1. We want to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(\frac{1}{x}) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$. For this to happen, both limits have to be equal to some $l$.
2. The definition of limit is $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(\frac{1}{x}) = l \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $|f(\frac{1}{x}) - l| < \epsilon $ is true $\forall x : 0 < x < \delta$.
3. Likewise $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = l \iff \forall \epsilon' > 0, \exists M > 0$ such that $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon'$ is true $\forall x > M$.
4. As you noted, $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$, which means that $\forall N > 0, \exists \delta' > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{x} > N$ is true $\forall 0 < x < \delta'$ (i.e., the function grows as high as you want it to).

---

Now, let's assume that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = l$, and let's prove that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(\frac{1}{x}) = l$ (i.e., we need to verify (2) is true). Imagine we're given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, and we need to produce a $\delta$ that makes (2) be true.

If we set $\epsilon' = \epsilon$ in (3), that produces an $M$ such that $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon, \forall x > M$. Furthermore, if we take $N = M$ in (4), we get back a $\delta' > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{x} > M, \forall 0 < x < \delta'$. Hence, if we produce $\delta = \delta'$, we get that:

1. $\frac{1}{x} > M, \forall 0 < x < \delta$
2. $|f(\frac{1}{x}) - l| < \epsilon, \forall 0 < x < \delta$

Which is exactly what we wanted to prove.

---

The argument above proved only that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = l \implies \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(\frac{1}{x}) = l$. The other way around is similar:

1. We'll assume $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(\frac{1}{x}) = l$, and want to prove that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = l$.
2. To do so, given an $\epsilon'$, we'll want to find the appropriate $M$ that makes (3) true.
3. Use (2) and (4) to come up with such an $M$

Comment: You could possibly interpret the original statement as including cases such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(1/x) = -\infty$, and similarly for a limit of $+\infty$.  Of course, the proofs of these statements are also straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Everything boils down to what you mean by $x \rightarrow a$.
One thing that makes things more complicated, is that $\infty \not \in \mathbb{R}$.
And because of that, you give $x \rightarrow \infty$ a special meaning.

To make things worse, **usually** $x \rightarrow a$ does not mean anything!!!
\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(a)
\end{equation*}
has a meaning.
But $x \rightarrow a$ has no meaning alone.

You want to conclude that
\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)
  =
  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).
\end{equation*}
In a sense,
you might want use that
\begin{equation*}
  x \rightarrow \infty
  \Leftrightarrow
  1/x \rightarrow 0. 
\end{equation*}
But this is nonsense if you do not have a meaning for $x \rightarrow a$.
So, just manipulating the symbols, as you do, is not a very formal proof.

It is true, however, that you can try to treat $\infty$ not in a special way.
For example, in $\mathbb{R}$,
when you talk about $x \rightarrow 0$,
you are talking about the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.
You are talking about $x$ approaching $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Two ways of thinking about $x \rightarrow 0^+$ are:

1. Easier: restricting the domain of $f$ to $[0,\infty)$.
2. Fancier: giving $\mathbb{R}$ a different topology.
   For example, using sets like $[0,a)$ to generate it.

I will choose the easier one.

And when you talk about $x \rightarrow \infty$???
What are you talking about? Some options:

1. Give to it a special meaning, different from the meaning of $x \rightarrow a \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Add $\infty$ to $[0,\infty)$, creating $[0,\infty]$.
   And then, give it a topology.

If you give $[0,\infty]$ the "right topology", you will see that $x \mapsto 1/x$ is a homeomorphism for $[0,\infty]$ onto itself. In this case, $1/x \rightarrow 0$ and $x \rightarrow \infty$ are "equivalent". Of course, here "equivalent" depends on what you mean by $x \rightarrow a$.

This is much more complicated that what you are trying to do... but I would say that **homeomorphism** is the key concept behind your intuition.